# Variable is categorized by 0 or 1 - how do I work with this?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with the "titanic" package used by many different R courses. It's extremely difficult for me, though, because whether a person survived or not is determined either by a 0 (didn't survive) or a 1 (survived). I'm trying to create a basic bar plot, but can't seem to sum up the 1s for each Sex - or any other variable.

```
library(tidyverse)
install.packages('titanic')
library(titanic)
```

Just a little bit of transformation:

```
titanic <- titanic_train %>%
+     select(Survived, Pclass, Sex, Age, SibSp, Parch, Fare) %>%
+     mutate(Survived = factor(Survived),
+            Pclass = factor(Pclass),
+            Sex = factor(Sex))
```

I tried to determine the number of female and male survivors via summarise():

```
titanic %>% group_by(Sex) %>% summarise(., survived = count(Survived))

titanic %>% group_by(Sex) %>% summarise(., survived = sum(Survived))
```

And I tried to create a bar plot:

```
ggplot(titanic, mapping = aes(Sex, Survived)) + geom_bar()
ggplot(titanic, mapping = aes(Sex, sum(Survived))) + geom_bar()
ggplot(titanic, mapping = aes(Sex, count(Survived))) + geom_bar()
```

Will someone please show me how to work with a variable like "Survived" in the titanic dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try summarising before plotting like this. Also `Survived` is a numeric binary variable so in order to use it, you can transform it to `factor()` in the `aes()`. You can set the pipeline directly using `group_by()` with the required variables and then `summarise()`. As you want counts you can use `n()` function. Here the code, where I have used `titanic_train` dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(titanic)
data("titanic_train")
#Code
titanic_train %>% group_by(Sex,Survived) %>% summarise(N = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sex, N,fill=factor(Survived))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  labs(fill='Survived')
```

Output:

[image]

Or if you want a bar per each class, try this:

```
#Code 2
titanic_train %>% group_by(Sex,Survived) %>% summarise(N = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sex, N,fill=factor(Survived))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  labs(fill='Survived')
```

Output:

[image]

Or if you want to use `count()` you can sketch next code:

```
#Code 3
titanic_train %>% count(Sex,Survived) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sex, n,fill=factor(Survived))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  labs(fill='Survived')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: what exactly does stat = 'identity' do within geom_bar() ?

Comment: @ReeNadeau It is a method to create the bars based on the values in the variable, you can also define other methods like `stat=count` which will count the values instead of displaying them as they appear in your dataframe!